# Sitecore upload, use item language instead of context language

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-media-library

I'm working on a website using Sitecore 8 Update 2.
I'm also using the Email Experience Manager module 3.1.1 rev. 150811.

In this module there is a FileList field, it opens the default media library box.

I use this field in several templates to be able to add documents ( word, pdf, ... )

[image]

Here you can upload a document. " Upload Media ".
[image]

We have 4 languages on our website, the problem here is that the newly created media item is always created in english. This is an issue as we want the media item to be created for the same language as the current item language.

As best as i can tell the item is created using the context language ( = english ).

Can i override and/or pass along what language i want the item to be created for ?

Comment: Are you uploading the images as versioned or unversioned media?  I believe unversioned is the default, and so the language wont matter.

Comment: uploaded as versioned

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading your media, try to change your language version then upload the media item.

Thanks